# Am I using Rust's bitvec_simd in the most efficient way?

Tags: performance, optimization, rust, bitvector

I'm using bitvec_simd = "0.20" for bitvector operations in rust.

I have two instances of a struct, call them `clique_into` and `clique_from`. The relevant fields of the struct are two bitvectors `members_bv` and `neighbors_bv`, as well as a vector of integers which is called `members`. The `members_bv` and `members` vector represent the same data.

After profiling my code, I find that this is my bottleneck (in here 41% of the time): checking whether the members (typically 1) of `clique_from` are all neighbors of `clique_into`.

My current approach is to loop through the members of `clique_from` (typically 1) and check each one in turn to see if it's a neighbor of `clique_into`.

Here's my code:

```
use bitvec_simd::BitVec;
use smallvec::{smallvec, SmallVec};

struct Clique {
  members_bv: BitVec,
  members: SmallVec<[usize; 256]>,
  neighbors_bv: BitVec,
}

fn are_cliques_mergable(clique_into: &Clique, clique_from: &Clique) -> bool {
  for i in 0..clique_from.members.len() {
    if !clique_into.neighbors_bv.get_unchecked(clique_from.members[i]) {
      return false;
    }
  }
  return true;
}
```

That code works fine and it's fast, but is there a way to make it faster? We can assume that `clique_from` almost always has a single member so the inner for loop is almost always executed once.

It likely comes down to this:

```
if !clique_into.neighbors_bv.get_unchecked(clique_from.members[i])
```

Is get_unchecked() the fastest way to do this? While I have written this so it will never panic, the compiler doesn't know that. Does this force Rust to waste time checking if it should panic?

Comment: I should mention that it would be nice not to have to maintain the SmallVec of members; that only exists for this method. However, this method is so hot that if the SmallVec makes it faster it's worthwhile.

Answer (score 0):

You are attempting to test if two sets are disjoint or not. The fastest way to do this is to `and` together two bit vectors to form the intersection and test `is_empty` on the generated set.

To accomplish this, you will need to store data in sets of equal size.